# What are `\.` and `i` in a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, literals

Could someone tell me what the `\.` and `i` on the `:with`-line in the following are used for?

```
validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with:    %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG file.'
}
```

Comment: The real question you should be asking is, What is `%r{..}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%r{}` is used for regular expressions.

`\.` is looking for the literal character `.`. You need the `\` to escape because just using `.` means something else entirely (any character matches).

`i` is used for case insensitive searches.

Essentially, your regex is matching for anything that ends in `.gif`, `.jpg` or `.png`. These could also be something like `.GiF` because of the case insensitive search.

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby, you can create *Regexps* using the %r{...} literals.

The following are [*metacharacters*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Metacharacters+and+Escapes) `(, ), [, ], {, }, ., ?, +, *.` They have a specific meaning when appearing in a pattern. To match them literally they must be backslash-escaped.

`i` is for [case insensitive](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options) match.